# Scalable REST API authentication

Tags: authentication

I'm trying to implement authentication with React and Node via REST API and getting really confused. In many articles I see the JWT way to handle the authentication, but I also see that this is not very secure, so many suggest to use sessions with HTTP only cookie, but how does this makes any sense if REST API is stateless and adding sessions to it will hurt the scalability.

I'm a newbie and it really hurt my brain to understand what is the best practice when dealing with REST API authentication that can scale and be secure.

Comment: Welcome to the community. You mostly need to make authentication *AND* authorization. `HTTPOnly` setting of a cookie is only there to make sure JS cannot access the cookie with the Bearer token (JWT) inside.

Comment: *"but I also see that this is not very secure"* - this is **wrong** statement. 1) There are many articles from people who don't understand it. 2) May be misunderstood some article. 3) Please provide some links to such articles. Then it will be clear if the articles are wrong or you misunderstood them.

Comment: 4) Declaring a cookie `HTTPOnly` has nothing to do with sessions. This only means, that the client code cannot access it. But browser will still send this cookie with each request to the corresponding domain. It doesn't have any impact on scalability.

Answer (score 1):

JWTs themselves are industry standard and can be secure if used correctly within your entire system (client, API, back-end).  See more information at https://jwt.io/introduction for example.

A common question is how should the client browser store the JWT.  If stored in browser localStorage and accessed via JavaScript, it can be subject to some client-side scripting attacks.  That's why some people recommend storing the JWT in a cookie, marked "secure" and "httpOnly".

Using cookies doesn't necessarily mean using sessions; using JWTs doesn't necessarily mean not using cookies.